# docker port mapping not forwarding traffic

Tags: docker, asterisk, freepbx

I try to use this container: https://hub.docker.com/r/tiredofit/freepbx/

For that i have created this compose file: 
`https://pastebin.com/CkL1y0jd`

I have proxied port 80 to my internal IP 172.20.0.45. This works great. But Port 5160 is not reachable from the outside.

On my Docker host i have ran

```
ngrep -W byline -d eno1 port 5160
```

This gives me the following output:

```
U 192.168.30.22:54194 -> 192.168.50.20:5160
REGISTER sip:pbx.UsualyMyDomain.ch:5160;transport=UDP SIP/2.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 212.XX.XX.XXX:54194;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---9bb8a42e6116af86;rport.
Max-Forwards: 70.
Contact: <sip:120@212.XXX.XXX.XXX:54194;rinstance=c4ebbf8b0a8fd276;transport=UDP>.
To: "4141XXXXXXX"<sip:120@pbx.UsualyMyDomain.ch:5160;transport=UDP>.
From: "4141XXXXXXX"<sip:120@pbx.UsualyMyDomain.ch:5160;transport=UDP>;tag=b4afdd24.
Call-ID: uXyh0WASXl2Cpp3oD0RYtw...
CSeq: 2 REGISTER.
Expires: 60.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE.
User-Agent: Zoiper rv2.9.RC37-15-g9fc1f76ee4.
Allow-Events: presence, kpml, talk.
Content-Length: 0.
```

But if i run the above command inside of my container, then i get no packets at all:

```
ngrep -W byline -d eno1 port 5160
interface: eno1 (172.20.0.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 5160 )
```

So where do i have to search for problems now?

```
netstats -tln
```

shows:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5160                 :::*                    LISTEN      13316/docker-proxy
```

But no UDP6 or UDP.

Could that be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

For all those out there who find a similar problem. 
Read this: http://bhashitparikh.com/2016/02/03/when-port-forwarding-didnt-work-in-docker.html

One of the problems was that you must insert your Docker IP under SIP-CHAN Settings as bind address. Then also use static-ip and enter your docker ip.

And last but not least, add this to the compose file:

- 5160:5160/udp
- 5060:5060/udp

Otherwise it will only listen to tcp traffic!
now it works :)